# Would believing the coming again of the Son of Man has already happened be considered heretical by the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-matthew, heresy, second-coming

Some Christians hold that the Second Coming of Jesus is yet to come, and some hold it has already happened (certain kinds of preterism).

Would holding that Jesus in the Olivet discourse (Matthew 24:30, "They will see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven, with power and great glory.") was prophesying an event that has already happened (say, associated with the siege of Jerusalem and destruction of the Second Temple) be considered heretical by the Catholic Church?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Would believing the coming again of the Son of Man has already happened be considered heretical by the Catholic Church?**

The short answer is **yes**, as it definitely goes against the traditional point of view of the Church and almost all Catholics would not accept it. It also goes against the [Apostles Creed](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01629a.htm): ***"He will come again to judge the living and the dead."***

The constant tradition of the Church believes the Second Coming of Christ has yet to happen.

Prophecy is generally not accepted as being complete until the events of the things prophesied have fulfilled their course. The Church has never accepted that the prophecies concerning the Second Coming of Christ have been fulfilled. In fact, I have never known any Catholics who have expressed this perspective. The Church simply believes it is yet to come. To believe otherwise is not heresy, but is not official stance of the Church.

There is a lot of speculation on this subject matter, even within the Catholic Church, but the vast, vast majority of the faithful hold that the Second Coming is yet to come.

> It is the traditional view of Roman Catholics and Orthodox Christians, preserved from the early Church, that the Second Coming will be a sudden and unmistakable incident, like "a flash of lightning".[Mt 24:27] They hold the general view that Jesus will not spend any time on the earth in ministry or preaching, but come to judge mankind. They also agree that the ministry of the Antichrist will take place right before the Second Coming. - [Second Coming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Coming)

Comment: Here's a specific link that seems fairly official re the Apostles' Creed from the Catholic Encyclopedia. https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01629a.htm In particular " As a result of this intimate association with the liturgy and teaching of the Church, the Apostles' Creed has always been held to have the authority of an ex cathedra utterance. It is commonly taught that all points of doctrine contained in it are part of the Catholic Faith, and cannot be called in question under pain of heresy (St. Thomas, Summa Theologica, II-II:1:9)."

Comment: So it seems if a preterist view excludes a possible *other* coming again (after the supposed preterist one), it is heretical. It's not so clear if the Apostles' Creed excludes the possibility that Christ has already come once to judge *some* of the living and the dead, and then will come again (presumably to judge the *rest*).